# How do I set the path automatically on login when ssh'ing to a Windows machine?

Tags: windows, ssh

I want to set the path on a Windows server so that when I log in via SSH the directory

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\libexec\git-core
```

is in my path.

I can ssh to the server, but %PATH% does not contain the directory above.

Is there are file like ".profile", ".bashrc", or ".login" where I can add a directory to the path?

Answer (score -1):

You can also set your path from the command line with

```
setx PATH "%PATH%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\libexec\git-core"
```

I'm having the same problem as you, though, which is my path is different when I'm at a command prompt at the keyboard vs logged in remotely. Still trying to figure that one out.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question.  Maybe I wasn't clear, but I want the path to be set automatically when I ssh.  This is so that git will work properly.